# Storing and Retrieving Long Formatted Text from Database

Tags: html, reactjs, database, text

I have react app that stores user-written stories in a database and retrieves them for later viewing. I am having trouble finding a way to maintain the formatting of the original story when retrieving them to display on a web page. Here's what I have tried so far:

- storing as plain text
- storing as html (keeps the html tags as strings)
- saving and storing the text file as an epub and using react-reader (error 403 when retrieving epub file, CORS is enabled)

All that is left that I can think of is encoding the text into some form that captures special formatting characters or maybe saving it as markdown. Any thoughts and opinions on what works/how people usually do this?

Comment: UPDATE: react-reader does work with other epub file urls, I think that since I'm using Directus cms, theres some type of config that isn't allowing the resource to be fetched despite permissions being open.

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the html idea.

Nowadays one of the lightest and well known formats is Markdown

Also in js there are several libraries which convert the plain markdown into rich content

[image]

You could create stories with markdown tables.

If your user is not able to write markdown, your oy choice will be html.

To store files will complicate your architecture & infrastructure. Please don't store files in your database. Use some storage service.

Comment: Yes, I started messing around with react-markdown and so far this seems to be doing the trick. The formatting luckily is just making a heading and breaking paragraphs so nothing too complex.

I've heard that before, Is it because the size is relatively large and maintenance gets more difficult with scale? What do you mean by storage service, like a cms?